# Is it possible to disable Update/Delete on EF Code First entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to to create an EF entity that allows your to create records but disable update and deletes.  I have data object that I want to allow code to create records in DB but they should not be allowed to change or delete them.  I'm using EF code first approach.

Comment: Isn't it possible to encapsulate your context in a Repository that only supports adding entities?

Comment: That was option 2 but managed to override the change tracker as offered below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can override the `SaveChanges` method of your `DbContext` and can prevent that.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (DbEntityEntry entity in this.ChangeTracker.Entries)
    {
        if (entity.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified)
            return;
        // more logic, depending on your needs
    }

    base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Going to use this and try changing the state for update/deleet to unchanges (entity.State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;) and see if this allows other types of changes to be saved.

Comment: As mentioned above, it worked brilliant with change the state to unchanged so the changes never got recorded.  Thanks.